# Solving for x in numpy.linalg.solve as done in Maple

Tags: python, numpy, maple

I am trying to use Python to avoid having to work on my school's computers for MATLAB or Maple. I am trying to do the simple task of finding x in Ax=b. I have two vectors, u = [1,1,1] and v = [1,-1,2], which make up A. For b, my vector is [1,5,-1]. I know the solution is [3,-2], which is confirmed when using LinearSolve in Maple... `LinearSolve(<u|v>,<1,5,-1>)`. In Numpy, my code to solve this is as follows...

```
import numpy as np
#Define vector u = (1,1,1)
u = [1,1,1]

#define vector v = (1,-1,2)
v = [1,-1,2]
x = np.array([u,v])
x = np.transpose(x)
y = np.array([1,5,-1])

try: 
    print(x,y)
    np.linalg.solve(x,y)
except Exception as e:
    print("The equation cannot be solved. "+str(e))
```

I have tried both transposing the matrix A, but that did not result in anything different than when I didn't. They both resulted in the exact same output with respect to the error message, which is shown below. The only difference is matrix x is a 2x3 one when I don't call transpose, which I believe is not what I want.

```
[[ 1  1]
 [ 1 -1]
 [ 1  2]] [ 1  5 -1]
The equation cannot be solved. Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

I have read through the docs, and am not understanding why I cannot get a solution here. From my understanding, this should result in the following equation... 3[1,1,1] - 2[1,-1,2] = [1,5,-1].

Answer (score 1):

Your A matrix is not square and therefore [solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) can't be used.

> Computes the “exact” solution, x, of the **well-determined**, i.e., full rank, linear matrix equation ax = b.
>
> ...
>
> a must be **square** and of **full-rank**, i.e., all rows (or, equivalently, columns) must be linearly independent; if either is not true, use lstsq for the least-squares best “solution” of the system/equation.

As stated above, you probably want to use [lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq).

> Solves the equation a x = b by computing a vector x that minimizes the Euclidean 2-norm || b - a x ||^2. The **equation may be under-, well-, or over- determined** (i.e., the number of linearly independent rows of a can be less than, equal to, or greater than its number of linearly independent columns). If a is square and of full rank, then x (but for round-off error) is the “exact” solution of the equation.

(Bold text annotated by me.)

Using:

```
np.linalg.lstsq(x,y)
```

the code returns `[3, -2]` (as first tuple-element of the result) as you did expect.

Matlab is in general a bit more intransparent / magic in regards to some operations like solving Ax=b (which algorithm will be used). Numpy on the other hand is a bit more low-level and needs more user-support (which is not a bad thing per se).

Excerpt from the [matlab-docs](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html):

> x = A\B solves the system of linear equations A*x = B. The matrices A and B must have the same number of rows. MATLAB® displays a warning message if A is badly scaled or nearly singular, but performs the calculation regardless.
>
> If A is a scalar, then A\B is equivalent to A.\B.
>
> If A is a square n-by-n matrix and B is a matrix with n rows, then x = A\B is a solution to the equation A*x = B, if it exists.
>
> If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a matrix with m rows, then A\B returns a least-squares solution to the system of equations A*x= B.